# How to get micro seconds with time stamp in Perl?

Tags: perl

This might be a silly question but I am not able to find answer to it:

I have a Python code which is printing time-stamp like this:

```
2015-05-19 22:27:00.688441
```

The code which produces this string looks something like this:

```
print str(datetime.datetime.strptime(time_value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

I would like to do the same in Perl (version 5.14). I can get all parts of this string except the last fractional part `(%f)`.

How do I get exact same string in Perl?

PS: I tried using `Time::HiRes` module.

```
use Time::HiRes;
my ($seconds, $microseconds) = gettimeofday;
```

If somehow I can use `$seconds` to `localtime()`, is it possible? If so, then how?

Extension to original question: If I have a variable `$time_value` -- lets assume that I have retrieved a time stamp string in this variable from somewhere, how can I format this to required format i.e. time stamp with microseconds?

Comment: what problem did you have trying to use Time::HiRes?  re extension: what is $time_value?

Comment: I am new to Perl, so I am not sure about how to use Time::HiRes for this particular case. I am able to use it as per the documentation but not for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way most similar to how Python does it is to install and use [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime).  Note that microseconds are not a part of the standard `strptime` format.  DateTime uses `%N` for fractional seconds.  `%6N` means factional seconds to 6 places (microseconds).

```
# `DateTime->now` uses seconds, so we have to supply our own
# hires time.
use Time::HiRes qw(time);
use DateTime;

print DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => time )->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N');
```

Comment: This code gave me output as: 2015-10-20 23:34:10.000000
Anything missing since we are getting all 0s at the end?

Comment: @KedarJoshi Ahh. The format is correct, but `DateTime->now` isn't using microseconds. I'll put up a better example.

Comment: @Schewern : I am trying to get a timestamp using 
my $mtime = (stat $filename)[10];
how do i convert this into required format any idea?

Comment: The problem is stat function returns mtime as seconds since epoch time.. how do i get microseconds here?

Comment: Nevermind, got it. Time::HiRes has a "stat" function itself

Answer (score 4):

```
$ perl -E'
   use DateTime qw( );

   my $time = 1445400376.20984;

   my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => $time, time_zone => "local" );
   say $dt->strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N");
'
2015-10-20 21:06:16.209840
```

(Remove `time_zone => "local"` for UTC.)

But DateTime is a bit heavy. POSIX offers the lightest solution.

```
$ perl -E'
   use POSIX qw( strftime );

   my $time = 1445400376.20984;

   my $microsecs = ($time - int($time)) * 1e6;
   say sprintf("%s.%06.0f", strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime($time)), $microsecs);
'
2015-10-20 21:06:16.209840
```

(Change `localtime` to `gmtime` for UTC.)

If you don't already have the time, you can use Time::HiRes's `time` in the first snippet and `gettimeofday` for the second.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use [Time::Moment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment). In the interest of full disclosure, I am the author of Time::Moment.

**Local time:**

```
$ perl -MTime::Moment -E'
say Time::Moment->now    
                ->strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N");
'
2015-10-21 19:48:56.333887
```

**UTC time:**

```
$ perl -MTime::Moment -E'                                                                                       
say Time::Moment->now_utc
                ->strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N");
'
2015-10-21 17:48:57.805921
```

Comment: That module looks like the DateTime alternative I've been looking for.

Comment: Now, I can add time-stamp to my log files and precisely monitor the time of event occurred at miliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Using Time::Piece, which doesn't support fractional seconds, by tacking them on at the end:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
use Time::HiRes;

my ($seconds,$microseconds) = Time::HiRes::gettimeofday;
my $str = sprintf '%s.%06d', gmtime($seconds)->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), $microseconds;
```

Comment: `from_epoch` will take fractional seconds.